# Deleting an element from a List in Scala using a loop and only a loop

Tags: scala

I've written this code where I'm copying the elements from one List to another List to exclude one element,I'm using a for loop and inside the for loop there is an if statement where it says to copy all the elements to the new List which are not equal to the value l and exclude the element which has the index that i entered , the code is not working and not copying the elements , please someone tell me what's wrong with

```
object delete {
def delete_Element(symbol:List[Char],l:Int): List[Any] ={
var copy_Symbol=List[Char](4)
for (i <- 0 until symbol.length) {
  if (i!=l) {
     copy_Symbol(i) = symbol(i)
  }
}
  copy_Symbol
}
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val symbol=List('a','b','c','d')
println(symbol)
println("Enter an index to delete an element from the List : ")
val l=scala.io.StdIn.readInt
print(delete_Element(symbol:List[Char],l:Int))
}
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. Vars are bad. Accessing `List` elements by index is even worse.  `Any` is code smell. Also `List` is immutable (you can't add things to it), `List[Char](4)` does not do what you seem to think it does, and `copy_Symbol(i) = symbol(i)` should not compile at all. And you (almost) never need to write  a loop (or a `var`) in scala. `def del(s: List[Char], l: Int) = s.zipWithIndex.collect { case (c, i) if i != l => c }`

Comment: You are using a **List** like it was an **Array** that will never work. Please learn the language first, not just the syntax but the stdlib and the common idioms.

Comment: This is like trying to use a screwdriver to drill a hole in a piece of wood. It can be done, but there's a better way. Have you thought about simply filtering out the undesired element? e.g., https://scastie.scala-lang.org/67tJpauITyKjQf1SpDpDQA

Comment: `var`s are not inheritantly bad, but it is recommended to use immutable objects with `val` whenever possible. Dima's solution is the best one in this case, although it can be improved with view (and that's another topic). You can also yield from for loop to achieve similar functionality.

Comment: Guys I understand , but I've been asked to use a loop and only a loop , no filtering , nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List` is immutable collection, so you can't update it's elements. Consider using some mutable collection such as `ListBuffer` and then converting it to `List`.

```scala
  def delete_Element(symbol: List[Char], l: Int): List[Any] = {
    val copy_Symbol = ListBuffer[Char]()
    for (i <- 0 until symbol.length) {
      if (i != l) {
        copy_Symbol.addOne(symbol(i));
      }
    }
    copy_Symbol.toList
  }
```

But better not to use loops for such purposes, you could try more clear and short solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12866536/4699692 :

```scala
def delete_Element(symbol: List[Char], l: Int): List[Any] = {
    symbol.patch(l, Nil, 1)
}
```